# Giving birth to a child in UK

Tags: united-kingdom

I am currently in the UK on a visit visa since the 13th of October 2018 with my UK husband. He has British citizenship by Descent through his father. Now I am pregnant and my due date is on the 7th of September 2019. I have to go to my home country within 6 months of my first entry, so I have to be in my home country by April.

The thing is that I want to deliver my baby in the UK so that the child automatically acquires citizenship. Regarding the spouse visa, we will be able to submit it after July, so I am afraid we might not get a reply until after my delivery.

Is there any way I can arrange to have my child born in the UK with these constraints?

Comment: You can go back in a couple months and return three months later. You can choose to overstay. We don’t do settlement visas here. You can check on our sister site, expatriates.

Comment: It seems to me that the best chance of getting the spouse visa in time is to return home immediately, and then apply (bearing in mind that you may not be allowed to fly in the final month of your pregnancy). Why do you have to wait until July to submit your spouse visa application?

Comment: Has long has your husband already been living in the UK?

Comment: My husband will continue his 6 months payslips on July so i have to wait till then.

Comment: My husband has been living in the UK since september 2017

Comment: @NNegm Have you read the [detailed guidance](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-fm-family-members)? Having 6 months of payslips with the current employer is not a requirement. See section 5.3 onwards. If he's worked somewhere less than 6 months, there are other ways to fulfill the requirement, although it is a bit more complex.

Comment: Your child would also be a British citizen if born in an overseas territory, though depending on your home country that might not be very helpful.